# Math symbol question in Algebraic Topology about symbol that kinda looks like restriction symbol, but not really

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

I'm doing some reading, and keep encountering a symbol I'm unsure of. In Munkres' *Elements of Algebraic Topology*, and in Chapter 1, Lemma 2.3 he has the following:

> Lemma 2.3. A map $f: |K| \to X$ is continuous if and only if $f | \sigma$ is continuous for each $\sigma \in K$.

The part I'm confused about is the $f | \sigma$, it seems like a restriction, but also not.

Then in Zomorodian, Carlsson 2005 *Computing Persistent Homology*, they write in Theorem 2.1 (structure) (page 4):

> **Theorem 2.1 (structure)** If $D$ [a ring] is a principal ideal domain
> (PID), then every finitely generated $D$-module is isomorphic to a
> direct sum of cyclic $D$-modules.  That is, it decomposes uniquely
> into the form [the first direct sum is smaller than the one in the
> parentheses, but couldn't figure out how to make smaller]
>
> $$ D^{\beta} \oplus \bigg(\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}D/d_iD\bigg) $$
>
> for $d_i \in D$, $\beta \in \textbf{Z}$ [integers], such that
> $d_i|d_{i+1}$.

I'm unclear what they mean by $d_i|d_{i+1}$ here.  It seemed like the same thing from Munkres above at first glance, so thought to check up on it.

I don't have *too* much formal education in this department (an undergrad class in topology, an undergrad class in algebra, and a persistent homology project), so maybe my not-knowing this indicates some glaring gap in my knowledge.  If so, please fill me in a good reference!

edit: Munkres says something similar to the definition from Zomorodian and Carlsson.  Defining as follows:

> **Theorem 4.3.** (The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian
> groups).  Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group.  Let $T$ be
> its torsion subgroup.
>
> (a) There is a free abelian subgroup $H$ of $G$ having finite rank
> $\beta$ such that $G = H \oplus T$.
>
> (b) There are finite cyclic groups $T_1,...,T_k$, where $T_i$ has
> order $t_i > 1$ such that $t_1 | t_2 | ... | t_k$ and
>
> $$ T = T_1 \oplus ... \oplus T_k $$
>
> (c) The numbers $\beta$ and t_1, ..., t_k are uniequely determined by
> $G$.

Here again, $t_1 | t_2 | ... | t_k$ means that, for example, $t_2$ is a multiple of $t_1$?

Comment: To get the smaller direct sum symbol, use `\oplus` instead of `\bigoplus`. In $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$ I expect that the vertical bar is for *divides*: $d_{i+1}$ is a multiple of $d_i$ in the ring $D$. The other one does appear to indicate the restriction of the map.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott wow haha sometimes simple naming logic flies right over my head!

That makes sense about the symbol...

Comment: So it seems then the notation I was missing out on was just from algebra rings

Comment: Yes, that’s how I read it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I added another definition from Munkres that is just for groups (similar to the Zomorodian,Carlsson definition).  Just want to confirm it is still division

Comment: Yes, it’s the same idea; those theorems are direct counterparts of each other.